# Authenticating a custom user in Django 1.5

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-1.5

I have a custom user in a Django 1.5 project, which uses the `email` field as the username:

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    my_custom_field = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

MyUser._meta.get_field_by_name('email')[0]._unique = True
MyUser.REQUIRED_FIELDS.remove('email')
```

If I try to authenticate that user like so:

```
auth_user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)
login(request, auth_user)
```

I get this:

```
Traceback:
File "/Users/user/dev/proj/app/core/views.py" in post
  39.             login(request, auth_user)
File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/proj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in login
  92.     request.session[BACKEND_SESSION_KEY] = user.backend
File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/proj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in inner
  203.         return func(self._wrapped, *args)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /signup
Exception Value: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'backend'
```

How am I supposed to authenticate a custom user?

Comment: What I meant was this `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ( 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')`

Comment: Did you set `AUTH_USER_MODEL`?

Comment: `authenticate` doesn't seem to be returning an actual User. Is it the standard method from django.contrib.auth? Are you sure email and password are correct?

Comment: Yes, I have `AUTH_USER_MODEL` set to `appname.MyUser` and `from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login`, email and password are correct since I just created the user earlier in that flow

Comment: Looks like something about my custom user implementation is wrong. Do I need to override `create_user()` for `MyUser`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My custom model didn't implement `create_user()` in its apparently-required custom manager.

Here's the full working code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager

class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=MyUserManager.normalize_email(email),
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        user = self.create_user(email,
            password=password,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    some_custom_field = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

MyUser._meta.get_field_by_name('email')[0]._unique = True
MyUser.REQUIRED_FIELDS.remove('email')
```

Django 1.5 "custom user" implementation is an abomination.

Answer (score 1):

What Django documentation is saying is

> If you’re entirely happy with Django’s User model and you just want to add some additional profile information, you can simply subclass django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser and add your custom profile fields

So the idea of AbstractUser is to use it only when you need to add a few additional fields to the user model without creating a separate db table like it was pre Django 1.5.

But when you need a different functionality (like using the email as username,which probably means you won't need the username field) the better approach is the extend the AbstractBaseUser class and set all the fields you need there. This way setting the `USERNAME_FIELD='email'` will work without writing custom create_user() method.